# Refresh button in React-admin

Tags: react-admin

I'm trying to access the refresh button in react-admin project. I tried using getElementsbyClassName it returns HTMLComponents Object but it isn't accessible i.e I can see the component on printing it to console but isn't accessible by code. Is there a way for me to disable this refresh button wherever I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure the exact use case here, but you can create your own custom AppBar that renders essentially whatever you want: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Theming.html#replacing-the-appbar.
also see this GitHub issue that mentions removing it entirely: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/3383

Within your custom AppBar you could have some logic checks within your custom AppBar if you know ahead of time when you'll want it disabled (like on a certain page/component).

If you need it to be more dyanimcally disabled, you could probably have a very high-level context/state to control that as well..

**NOTE: I have built a custom AppBar before, but I haven't done any selective rendering or disabling within it. So, I can't guarantee that this is exactly correct, but it fits with other custom components I've built.